# Issue extracting images from bagfile

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded a bagfile which contains rgb and depth images:

```
path:        kinectrgbdepthnew.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    6.7s
start:       Jun 23 2016 14:55:41.10 (1466686541.10)
end:         Jun 23 2016 14:55:47.85 (1466686547.85)
size:        395.9 MB
messages:    386
compression: none [386/386 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/Image [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
topics:      /camera/depth/image     193 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
             /camera/rgb/image_raw   193 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

But when I try to extract the rgb images

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="$(find imagesequencekinect)/kinectrgbnew.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I don't get all the images, it stops for this example at frame0062.jpg and if I keep openni2 running it starts saving images in live from frame0063..

```
[ INFO] [1466686708.317537964]: Saved image frame0062.jpg
[rosbag-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/jros/.ros/log/977b5f76-3941-11e6-8b71-5c260a35b6aa/rosbag-1*.log
[ INFO] [1466686708.452904753]: Saved image frame0063.jpg
```

I don't know why it doesn't save all the frames and why it starting color stream automatically

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237886/issue-extracting-images-from-bagfile/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer most likely has to do with the `~sec_per_frame` parameter of `extract_images`. It defaults to 0.1 seconds per frame, and your Kinect data is likely recorded at 30 seconds per frame. In fact (10/30)*193 ~= 64 which is right about where your `extract_images` node stops. Using this setup, I've never had very good luck getting out the exact number of images that were originally recorded. Presumably, if you change `~sec_per_frame` to be 0.033, you'll get most of the images.

One thing that I have had some luck with is [bag2video](https://github.com/OSUrobotics/bag2video) (not sure if you are ultimately trying to get videos).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-06-28**:
Yes you are right it works better but still don't get all the msg